# Good convention to use for SKU # when submitting iPhone app

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

Can someone give me a good convention to use when trying to come up with an SKU # for when I submit my app? IE something like produt_name_version or whatever. Have no clue what to put here or how it will impact future versions of my app.

Comment: Think ahead to the time you have galactic domination and you are in the control centre of your Death Star. Many screens overhead and you want a "see-at-a-glance" picture of what app controller is about to do the deed. I use the first 4 letters of app category-4 digit number ( I could have almost ten thousand )- first 4 letters of app name - type ( universal,iPhone,iPad, Watch,TVos and a Paid or Free suffix, like UTIL-0034-DEST-UNIV-F

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[From Apple's Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/Properties.html):

"A unique ID for your app in the Apple system **that is not seen by users**. You can use letters, numbers, hyphens, periods, and underscores. The SKU can’t start with a hyphen, period, or underscore. Use a value that is meaningful to your organization."

Hope that helps.

Edit: I always just use the name of the app. If the app name has spaces I use underscores.  Since it is internal, it won't ever change even after you update the version. You will use the SKU if you want to use Apple's java reporting tool (named auto-ingest) to download stats for the app programatically.

[**EDIT**: Apple has released a new tool for automated report downloading called [Reporter]](https://help.apple.com/itc/appsreporterguide/#/itc960331fbb)

Comment: Thanks. I know what it is though, just curious about what to use for it as a convention.

Comment: No problem, I have edited my answer based on your comments. Hope that helps! Please remember to up vote and/or mark question as the answer if it was helpful.

Comment: I did give you an upvote (was going to anyway) but imo not good form on the flow to ask for up votes or to mark as correct.

Answer (score 7):

I used `1` for my first app. Then `2` for the second. Works for me. Don't include a version. The SKU will never change.

Answer (score 6):

Use a short version of the apps name, plus the month it was released, and the year.

Example: myApp_02_2014